# Change of vectors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

We have two vectors $F1$ and $F2$ as shown in figure. The change of vectors is shown as $F2-F1$. Why it is it rather than taking negative of vector $F2$ i.e. $-F2$ and then adding it by head-to-tail rule So that change in vectors become $F1+(-F2)$

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$F1 - F2$ is the same as turning $F2$ around 'head to tail' and you get $-\Delta F$ or a vector, which is the same magnitude, but the opposite direction to $\Delta F$.

To get $\Delta F$ you need to reverse $F1$ as in the diagram I have modified from your diagram below
[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's because you want $F_1 + \Delta F = F_2$ by additivity of vectors (for a more rigorous approach, see the formalization of affine spaces). Hence, $\Delta F = F_2 - F_1$

PS: I couldn't comment because of my low reputation, so I made an answer for so little

Comment: Nice logic +1 - I editted to put the $\Delta$ symbol in